# Saving Plugin Data in Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jaxb, swt

I am developing an eclipse plugin in SWT, which has about 5 Wizard pages, the user needs to enter some data in each page. My pain point is whenever the user clicks the **NEXT** button, an **XML** must be generated behind which would keep updating on each **NEXT** press.

i.e. once the user clicks NEXT in the first page, a new XML is created and on successive pages, the user data must get appended to it. I am going to use **JAXB** to do this, but I am not sure how to proceed.

So, if anyone could give some suggestions and references please. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but the normal thing to do in a Wizard is to leave the creation of any output until the `performFinish` is called in your `Wizard` class.

Comment: ok, just imagine that I have an extra **SAVE** button in each Wizard Page and if i click this button, an output XML must be created which would hold the WizardPage data. Now this must be possible in all the pages, supposing the user just wants to abruptly end his session in 5th page (out of 10 Wizard pages), he will click the SAVE button, which must essentially create an XML, which would store all the data he has entered in those 5 pages. Later he must restore them and continue from the 6th page, thats what I am looking for.  I hope I must use `DialogSettings` for that, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the plugin's own bundle context to persist a data file in the storage area provided by the framework.

To initialize the data file in the bundle context, you need to override the start() method of the plugin's Activator class.

```
        public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
           super.start(context);
           setXMLDataFile(context.getDataFile("XMLDataFile.xml"));
           setWizardPage(context.getDataFile("WizardPageIndicator.txt"));
        }
```

Then make a static getter method in the same Activator for you to be able to retrieve/modify the data files for your use in your wizard.

Comment: thanks Harold. But couldn't understand whats that **setXMLDataFile** and **setWizardPage** methods.  Also, `WizardPageIndicator.txt?`  Could you please tell what data will be stored in this `XMLDataFile.xml`?